# What is the difference between landlord, lease tenant and tenant?

Tags: meaning

Is lease tenant the same as landlord?. I am having a rough time understanding this meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Landlords are people who rent something, typically some form of property, to other people which are called tenants. So, if you are renting out an apartment, you are called a tenant. And the guy who you pay for the right to occupy that apartment is called the landlord. Is that clear enough?

*lease tenant* is a nonexistent term. Where did you get it from?

Comment: provide the names of all persons who are the lease tenants of an apartment, where the rent of that apartment is higher than half of the lease tenant's salary.

Comment: I tried finding the phrase in Google Ngrams. It found lots of matches, but when I looked at the examples, they were always separated by a period of comma, e.g. "At the end of the lease, tenant must ..."

Comment: @TheMathNoob So it seems like your example is ideosyncratic, and "lease tenant" means the same thing as "tenant".